# jQuery select first input by name

Tags: jquery

I'm working on updating a site for a client. They got the form elements named like `selection[0]`, `selection[1]`, `selection[2]`, `selection[3]` for example. When the form is submitted to PHP it comes out as an array. In jQuery I want to select the selection[0] one.

I tried doing `$('input[name="selection[0]"]')` but no luck. Is it possible to select the first one by name some how? I would of done an ID instead but this form has the ID as the same for each of them, and the IDs are used for some existing jQuery validation plugin.

```
<select id="Snorkeling_Selection" name="Snorkeling_Selection[0]" class="validate[required]" style="padding:2px; border:thin solid #94B5C7; width:90%; height:23px; margin-bottom:8px; background:#FFF;">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="Traditional Snorkeling">Traditional Snorkeling</option>
    <option value="Power Snorkeling">Power Snorkeling</option>
</select>
```

and the select I was using `$('input[name="Snorkeling_Selection[0]"]')`

Comment: [This should work](http://jsfiddle.net/Xkn3G/).

Comment: Post your `HTML` code.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine, there's probably an error in the html somewhere - http://jsfiddle.net/hLaX5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After see your edit question... Try with [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/tumicike/1/edit)

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  $('#form').on('submit',function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();    

     var sel1 = $('#select option:eq(0)').prop('value');

     alert(sel1);
  });  
});
```

Comment: Thanks! `$('#Snorkeling_Selection:eq(0)').val()` worked.

Comment: You welcome.. but that `$('#Snorkeling_Selection:eq(0)').val()` worked? Don't forget `option` like this: `$('#Snorkeling_Selection option:eq(0)').val()`

Comment: Yep! Needed to select the select menu itself, not the first option. $('#Snorkeling_Selection').val() even works but seems to only go by the first ID. I know you're only allowed to have only 1 ID anyways but the original person who made it used the same ID over and over with this JS validater plugin they used.

Comment: Ah ok... now I get you :)

Comment: I could edit the html but most of it works good already and wasn't part of the job. Just an add-on.

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the "[" and "]" with \.

Fiddler: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JYLY9/

Example:

```
alert($('input[name="selection\\[2\\]"]').val());
```

HTML:

```
<input name="selection[1]" value="Test 1"></input>
<input name="selection[2]" value="Test 2"></input>
<input name="selection[3]" value="Test 3"></input>
```

Source:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \. For example, an element with
>   id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\.bar"). The W3C CSS
>   specification contains the complete set of rules regarding valid CSS
>   selectors. Also useful is the blog entry by Mathias Bynens on CSS
>   character escape sequences for identifiers.

- http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Interesting. Just did `$('input[name="Snorkeling_Selection\\[0\\]"]')` in the console and got back `[]`

Comment: sorry forgot fiddler demo